# Tool Orchestration System for windows, python codes

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, pipeline, devops, orchestration

I am new to orchestration and DevOps systems. I have a set of python modules, py1, py2, ..., py10.py. I also have input1, input2, ... , input10 as inputs for each of these modules in the form of text files. I also have 10 GPU enabled PCs connected to the same network with different username and passwords, (of course also ips). How can I distribute computations on .py files with these inputs from a master windows machine? all machines have windows 10 OS. I prefer to have the codes reside on the master machine and passed to (or copied) to minions.

I couldn't install Ansible on windows machines, but are there any good options to build this process quickly?

Comment: There is no DevOps system. It's a culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a broad question. I'd recommend building out your playbook on your local machine using a localhost target.

Look into the Copy module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html

This will distribute your python modules and text files to your hosts.

Once you've got a working module, build an inventory: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html

This will allow you to role out your playbook to the 10 hosts that you mention.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, unfortunately, I dont think Ansible is yet compatible with windows OS systems (master and minions). I agree Ansible might be probably the best option otherwise.

Comment: It looks ok to me:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_windows_modules.html